# Valgrind shows uninitialized variable in Fortran code

Tags: debugging, fortran, valgrind

I'm executing a valgrind (with memcheck tool) on the Fortran application.
Following error is shown by valgrind:

```
==17072==    at 0x806C4A2: prove_ (t10_isb.f90:1948)
==17072==    by 0x804E9F3: anal1_ (t10_isb.f90:2721)
==17072==    by 0x808EECC: MAIN__ (t10_isb.f90:6)
==17072==    by 0x808EF14: main (t10_isb.f90:8)
==17072==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==17072==    at 0x805ECDC: relplm_ (t10_isb.f90:3402)
==17072== 
==17072== 
==17072== ---- Attach to debugger ? --- [Return/N/n/Y/y/C/c] ---- y
```

Looking at the source code, I can't find anything suspicious:

Here, on the line 1948, uninitialized variable is used, so I guess it's either ER or EZ:

```
1943             if(NIT.eq.0) then
1944                  ER=ER/ekran
1945                  EZ=EZ/ekran
1946             end if
1947
1948                EM=DSQRT(ER*ER+EZ*EZ)
1949                ENO=-ER*PK(IEM*9-7)+EZ*PK(IEM*9-5)
1950
1951                IF(PK(IEM*9-8).GE.0.5D0) THEN
1952                   ESS=(ER*(PK(IEM*9-4)-F1)+EZ*(PK(IEM*9-6)-F2))
```

However, going up the call stack, we can see that these variables are initialized straight to calling the PROVE subroutine.

```
2716
2717          CALL VECMUL(SQ,JJK,CUR,NTP)
2718
2719          ER=0.D0
2720          EZ=0.D0
2721          CALL PROVE(E0,ES1,EN2,TE,TEPR,TEMI,TEMA,RB,ZB,QS,QP,R1P,Z1P,RONAT,ROHQ,RNQ,ZNQ,QNQ,NQ,IM1,IM2,IM3,IM4,IM5,IQQ,NTP,NIT,US,NFR,NTPE,NEM,NR,KEYP,MSYS,ekran,UK,RK,ZK,ER,EZ,F1,F2)
2722
2723          NPPP=NPAOLD+1
2724          DO I=NPPP,NPA
2725            N=I-NPAOLD
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: After reading up on valgrind and memcheck, turns out I should have paid more attention to this bit: Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation at 0x805ECDC: relplm_ (t10_isb.f90:3402).

Variables ER and EZ seem to be calculated here from some uninitialized variables (I'll have to dig some more to find out which ones).

Comment: did you compile with flag `-Wuninitialized`?

Comment: yes, few issues did show, but not this particular one. Turns out, the subroutine RELPLM was using a few variables that it expected to be static, but they were not.

Answer (score 0):

After reading up on valgrind and memcheck, turns out I should have paid more attention to this bit:

```
==17072==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==17072==    at 0x805ECDC: relplm_ (t10_isb.f90:3402)
```

I was expecting Valgrind to show me where the first read from the uninitialized was performed, however it only shows when "unitializedness" propagates to the variable used in syscall or conditional jump.

My issue was that the ER variable was initialized in the following way (not a real code, something similar in structure but in pseudo-C):

```
int relplm() {
   static int a11, a12, a13, a21, a31, a32, a33;

   if (value of top-left cell calculated) a11...
   if (value of top-center cell calculated) a12...
   if (value of top-right cell calculated) a13...
   if (value of left cell calculated) a21...
   if (value of right cell calculated) a23...
   if (value of bottom-left cell calculated) a31...
   if (value of bottom-right cell calculated) a32...
   if (value of bottom-right cell calculated) a33...

   if (any of the values changed) er=f(a11,a12,a13,a21,a23,a31,a32,a33)
}
```

It's hard to difficult that one of the variables is not declared static (or explicitly at all), given that in FORTRAN77 you can implicitly declare variable type by the letter its name starts from.